# Merging multiple related firebird select procedure using If else or case method

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, procedural-programming, firebird-3.0

How to merge this two firebird select procedure using this REFERENCE variable thru if else, case, or other method. If REFERENCE = 1 then the procedure 1 will display, if REFERENCE = 2 then the procedure 2 will display. I am trying to have 1 select procedure with conditions rather than 2 procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRINT_NON_REF1(
      M VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      Y VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      REFERENCE VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
    RETURNS(
      AP_PSTIONLVL_NON VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      AP_POSTION_NON VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      RANKING_MONTH VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      RANKING_YEAR VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
    AS
    BEGIN
      FOR
        SELECT
          '',
          '',
          RANKING_MONTH,
          RANKING_YEAR

        FROM APPLICANT
        WHERE RANKING_MONTH = :M AND RANKING_YEAR = :Y

        GROUP BY
        RANKING_MONTH,
        RANKING_YEAR

        INTO
          :AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
          :AP_POSTION_NON,
          :RANKING_MONTH,
          :RANKING_YEAR
      DO
        BEGIN
          SUSPEND;
        END

    END;
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRINT_NON_REF2(
      M VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      Y VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      REFERENCE VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
    RETURNS(
      AP_PSTIONLVL_NON VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      AP_POSTION_NON VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      RANKING_MONTH VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
      RANKING_YEAR VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
    AS
    BEGIN
      FOR
        SELECT
          AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
          AP_POSTION_NON,
          RANKING_MONTH,
          RANKING_YEAR

        FROM APPLICANT
        WHERE RANKING_MONTH = :M AND RANKING_YEAR = :Y

        GROUP BY
        AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
        AP_POSTION_NON,
        RANKING_MONTH,
        RANKING_YEAR

        INTO
          :AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
          :AP_POSTION_NON,
          :RANKING_MONTH,
          :RANKING_YEAR
      DO
        BEGIN
          SUSPEND;
        END

    END;
```

Comment: Why would you even do such SPs ? They can only degrade performance while adding no value. Why not issuing `SELECT`s directly ? In general you may toy with a construct like `select-1 UNION ALL select-2` with `WHERE` clauses in those `SELECT`s checking the flag parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a construct like this:

```
WITH
  Q_2 as (
      SELECT
        AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
        AP_POSTION_NON,
        RANKING_MONTH,
        RANKING_YEAR
      FROM APPLICANT
      WHERE RANKING_MONTH = :M
        AND RANKING_YEAR = :Y
      GROUP BY
        AP_PSTIONLVL_NON,
        AP_POSTION_NON,
        RANKING_MONTH,
        RANKING_YEAR
  ), 
  Q_1 as (
     SELECT
       '',
       '',
       RANKING_MONTH,
       RANKING_YEAR
     FROM APPLICANT
     WHERE RANKING_MONTH = :M 
       AND RANKING_YEAR = :Y
     GROUP BY
       RANKING_MONTH,
       RANKING_YEAR
 )

SELECT * FROM Q_2 WHERE :REFERENCE=2
   UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Q_1 WHERE :REFERENCE=1
```

Things to notice:

- Making a stored procedure which contains nothing but a single `SELECT` is bad idea in Firebird/Interbase. It will disable SQL optimizer job on joining, and will add nothing of value. Firebird is not MS SQL.
- The second query was set first in the `union`ed chain, because it is the first query where `UNION` takes column names and data types from. Would `Q_1` go first - the two anonymous columns would be a problem.
- Some database access libraries might have problems with several parameters in a query having same names. You might need to rename `:M` into `:M_1` and `:M_2`, etc. Or maybe not, test your library.
- Your specific programming language/library can have different SQL parameters syntax than `:name` used above. Especially, that Firebird itself on SQL level only supports unnamed parameters. Check your library documentation. You might also get insights reading code examples at https://bobby-tables.com/
- Read documentation about `UNION` and CTE (Common Table Expressions) at https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html